# `pub get` doesnt build .pub folder, and will then cause library build errors

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

I cloned down a repo and afterwards, I run pub get as usual.  The issue I have run into is that pub get will fail.  I looked at the errors which say:

```
[BuilderTransformer: Instance of 'LibraryBuilder' on MY_PACKAGE|primary]:
| Error running TemplateGenerator for MY_PACKAGE|lib/src/components/datetime/pickers/datetime_range/datetime_range_picker.dart.
| Error: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'library' was called on null.
| Receiver: null
| Tried calling: library
```

And What I determined is that when looking at the .pub directory, it was actually empty.

Does anyone know why this would be?  I am thinking that this is the reason why this error is called, because the path doesnt exist.

Assume: no ~/.pub-cache, ./.pub/, ./.packages

I can get additional information, but the dump from -v is very large.

When looking at a child project as a dependancy, it properly created the folder .pub/

Is there any insight from you all?

Comment: What Dart version are you using? Perhaps you are using a package that is not prepared for Dart 2?

Comment: I am using pub 1.24.3

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I was noticing that during the get process, it was never populating the .pub folder with the packages necessary to run.  It seems that the reason why those libraries dont exist because within the confines of the Project, they dont.  Somewhere within Pub I noticed it would get the packages, but it never saved them locally for some reason.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything with the `.pub` folder. That is maintained by `pub`. Perhaps you get an error when you run `pub get`/`pub upgrade`.

Comment: You are correct.  In some instances, get will eventually fail due to packages.  The issue which i have found odd is that a colleague with the same code has it work correctly. The fail to get was occuring during the LibraryBuilder phase of get.  Thats why i am confused.  Maybe there is something prior to it that is inhibiting .pub to properly populate.  Ill have to do more research into it.  Very odd if you ask me.